# CRT general equal for three congruences - correct?

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I saw someone ask a question regarding the congruences below.
$c≡1 \mod 143$

$c≡315 \mod 323$

$c≡167 \mod 667$

I tried to solve them with this equation: For any number of congruences $x≡a\mod n$, $N$ is the product of the moduli.

$c= \left[\Sigma_i = a_i \frac N{n_i} \left[\left(\frac N{n_i}\right)^{-1}\right]_{n_i}\right]_N$

I won't post all my the Extended Euclidean algorithm stuff but essentially these are the results I got:

$1\left( \frac {30808063} {143} \right)\left[\left( \frac {30808063} {143}  \right)^{-1}\right]_{143}$ +

$315\left( \frac {30808063} {323} \right)\left[\left( \frac {30808063} {323}  \right)^{-1}\right]_{323}$ +

$167\left( \frac {30808063} {667} \right)\left[\left( \frac {30808063} {667}  \right)^{-1}\right]_{667}$

$ = (215441*122 + 315*95381*286 + 167*49189*221 )\mod 30808063 = 3154410$

Is this correct?

Comment: The *structure* of the solution is correct. As to numerical verification, one can do it with a calculator, by calculating $3154410$ mod the three moduli.

Comment: Isn't that what I've done? 3154410 ≡ 3154410 mod 30808063...

Comment: $3154410\equiv116$ mod($143$)

Comment: It is always possible, at least for me, to make a numerical error, for example, in calculating inverses. So to check that the answer is indeed right, one can find the remainder when $3154410$ is divided by $143$. If it is $1$, one can begin to be pleased. Do the same thing for the other two moduli.

Comment: @lulu could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Not much to elaborate on, I just did the division (ok, I just asked my computer to the division for me).  I concur with the comment of @AndréNicolas ... it is frustratingly easy to make a numerical error in these things.  You always need to check.  to debug, I'd go back and check all the inverses by explicit computation.

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much

Comment: By the way, the other two congruences worked as you wanted.